# Limit of terms of Harmonic series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $s(n)$ be the smallest positive integer such that $1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+...+1/s(n)\geq{n}$

Find $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{s(n+1)}{s(n)}$

The values of $s(n)$ are

$s(1)=1, s(2)=4, s(3)=11, s(4)=31, s(5)=83, s(6)=227, s(7)=616 $ and so on

$\frac{s(2)}{s(1)}=4, \frac{s(3)}{s(2)}=2.75, \frac{s(4)}{s(3)}=2.8181..., \frac{s(5)}{s(4)}=2.677..., \frac{s(6)}{s(5)}=2.73493..., \frac{s(7)}{s(6)}=2.713...,$

I currently can't find a formula for $s(n)$ but from the calculations I can see that the ratio converges to $e$.

Any tips on how to prove this?

Answer (score 1):

The point is that the partial sums of the harmonic series are slowly increasing:
$$ H_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k} = \log n + \underbrace{\sum_{k\geq 1}\left[\frac{1}{n}-\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\right]}_{\gamma\,\approx\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}}+O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) $$
hence for any $\varepsilon>0$ and for any $N$ large enough, the smallest $n$ such that $H_n\geq N$ is bounded between $\exp\left(N-\gamma-\varepsilon\right)$ and $\exp(N-\gamma+\varepsilon)$. In particular the wanted limit equals $\exp(1)=e$.